# How to get innerHTML of div, which contains a div?

Tags: javascript

I'm a wondering how I can get `innerHTML` of `div` when it contains a `div` element and a text. My code looks like this:

```js
var outer = document.getElementById("outer").childNodes;
outer.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, `innerHTML` is getting the child `div` and the text, but I **only want the text**. Is it possible to make it without splitting or something?

Comment: Are you only wanting to return hello or return all the inner html (if it exists) of the child nodes?

Comment: Well that *is* the html inside the selected div, so it's correct.  If you just want the text then use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: What do you mean `text + text`? What does each `text` mean? @Archer he's not using jQuery

Comment: Yes i only want the text, hello in this case. I'll try .text();  :)

Comment: @clabe45 I knew that, but typo'd anyway - fixed now thanks :)

Comment: @Suttero - refresh the page.  My comment was bad, but now good.

Answer (score -1):

I would put `Hello` in a separate container if you can.

```js
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var firstItem = outer.children[0];
var text = firstItem.querySelector('.text').innerHTML;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <span class="text">Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

That way you have more control over it if you want to add more content